# Equation to find the Principal Unit Normal of a Bezier curve at $t$ ($0\leq t\leq1$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, spline, bezier-curve

I have recently been working on Bezier curves and have come across a very [interesting snippet of code](https://github.com/Kink3d/kSplines/blob/c4852d30dc8ef9125dd5715573a6c0aaf055b15d/com.kink3d.splines/Runtime/Util/SplineUtil.cs#L69) (don't worry its almost entirely mathematical) relating to finding the principal normal of a Bezier curve. It is the only of its kind I can find and there were no comments left as to how it was derived. The formula boils down to:

$$
(6t^2-6t)P_0 + (3t^2-4t+1)P_1 + (3t^2-2t)P_2 + (-6t^2+6t)P_3
$$

It claims to "Evaluate the normal for value $t$ between points $P_0$ and $P_3$".

My question is: how does this work, if it even does, and how was it derived so I can do the same for a Hermite curve as well. The go to answer for finding the normal would be to just use the second derivative crossed with the tangent and normalised, I have yet to see any other instance where a separate set of polynomials were used to calculate normals, but that is exactly what I need in order to have a generalised function for my program as it will not compute the vectors directly, only the polynomials at some value of $t$ to be used by a user, so I cannot use cross products, or any operations really, directly on the points $P_0,\ldots,P_3$.

If it helps any, I will include the functions I have to compute a point and the derivative in the same style as above, I know that the derivative is not usually represented as 4 distinct polynomials to multiply by, so I did some basic rearranging and have tested to confirm it works properly.

$$
P(t) = (-t^3 + 3t^2 - 3t + 1)P_0 + (3t^3 - 6t^2 + 3t)P_1 + (-3t^3 + 3t^2)P_2 + (t^3)P_3
$$
$$
P'(t) =  (-3t^2 + 6t - 3)P_0 + (9t^2 - 12t + 3)P_1 + (-9t^2 + 6t)P_2 + (3t^2)P_3 
$$

If you would like to see a more programming oriented version of this question, I originally posted this question on the primary stack overflow site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865132/equation-for-the-normal-of-a-point-on-a-bezier-curve) as I didn't know this site existed. I am making this post because I dont see that question getting much traction on the main site.

To quote myself:

> Any help would be appreciated, I have been going though countless
> scientific papers and code examples for so long that the word Bezier
> gives me ptsd-esque flashbacks at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you found is just plain wrong.

Try it on a simple example, say $P_0 = (0,0)$, $P_1 = (1,0)$, $P_2 = (1,1)$, $P_3 = (0,1)$.

It’s obvious that the curve normal at $t=0$ is in the direction $(0,1)$, but that’s not what your code returns.

The right way to calculate the (principal) normal of any curve is as follows:

1. Calculate the vector $B$ that is the cross product of the first and second derivative vectors. This gives you the direction of the curve’s binormal vector.
2. Calculate the cross product of $B$ and the first derivative vector. This gives you a vector in the direction of the curve’s principal normal.
3. If you want a unit normal, then unitize the result from step 2 by dividing it by it’s norm.

Of course, this won’t work if the first and second derivative vectors are linearly dependent. This will happen if they are parallel or one of them is zero. You’ll need special-case code to handle this situation.

At any given point on a curve, there are an infinite number of vectors that are normal to the curve. The procedure outlined above gives you the principal normal (i.e. a normal that lies in the curve’s osculating plane).

See sections 2.2 and 2.3 in [this book](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node24.html).

If you want the curve normal at its start point, where $t=0$, you can take some shortcuts. Let $U = P_1 - P_0$, and $V = P_2 - P_1$. Then the binormal vector $B$ is in the direction of the cross product $U \times V$, and the normal is therefore in the direction of $(U \times V) \times V$.

Comment: Thank you for this, there is a serious lack of clear and readable/well documented code involving bezier curves and its driving me nuts.  Ill leave the question open for a bit longer to get a general consensus but if nobody provides any new insights on it I will mark this as the answer. My big question now is why do they even have it and what does it actually do if not calculate the normal. Following the references on github, it is used twice in their code, but I also dont see examples of them showing a normal either.  I suppose thats something only the author can tell me.

Comment: Oh, also, I know from other code examples that sometimes end points have their own unique code associated with calculations, could you verify that the curves normal at somewhere at 0<t<1 is also incorrect? like 0.5 for example. I am still trying to learn bezier curves as i go so i am not confident enough to do it myself yet.

Comment: For my example curve, the normal at $t=0.5$ is obviously parallel to the x-axis. You can check whether your code computes this normal correctly. I’d guess that it doesn’t. Again, your code is wrong. I suggest you forget about it and write something new, using the approach that I outlined.

Comment: Actually, your code is so wrong that it doesn’t even produce a valid vector. A linear combination of points is a valid vector if and only if the coefficients add up to zero. You can see that this is the case for your first derivative formula, but not for the alleged normal formula.

Comment: I would like to point out, that is not my code. I did not write it, I merely came across it. The point and derivative equations were from my code though, which I tested and ensured were correct. I want nothing to do with whatever code is going on there lol.

Comment: Yeah. I know. writing “your code” is just me being lazy. No disrespect intended.